# How to pass Get parameter to url when url has "?" mark

Tags: 7

In my site clean urls is not working. As a result ?q is getting appended to the url.

My site url is http://abc.com/?q=user

I wrote a form in a page, and redirect to another view which is http://abc.com/?q=listings.

When I click on submit button in form page GET parameter are not getting appended correctly:
They are getting appended as http://abc.com/?field_list=3 which has to be like this http://abc.com/?q=listings&field_list=3.
I must use GET method in the form.

How should I redirect to URLs that contains "?q="?

How to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are redirecting from the form submission handler, you need to use code similar to the following one.

```
$form_state['redirect'] = array(
  'listings',
   array(
     'query' => array(
     'field_list' => '3',
   ),
);
```

That code is equivalent to calling `drupal_goto('listings, array('query' => array('field_list' => '3'))` which should never be used inside a form submission handler. In both the cases, the function that is called to build the URL is [url()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/url/7), which works when clean URLs are enabled, or not.

```
  // With Clean URLs.
  if (!empty($GLOBALS['conf']['clean_url'])) {
    $path = drupal_encode_path($prefix . $path);
    if ($options['query']) {
      return $base . $path . '?' . drupal_http_build_query($options['query']) . $options['fragment'];
    }
    else {
      return $base . $path . $options['fragment'];
    }
  }
  // Without Clean URLs.
  else {
    $path = $prefix . $path;
    $query = array();
    if (!empty($path)) {
      $query['q'] = $path;
    }
    if ($options['query']) {
      // We do not use array_merge() here to prevent overriding $path via query
      // parameters.
      $query += $options['query'];
    }
    $query = $query ? ('?' . drupal_http_build_query($query)) : '';
    $script = isset($options['script']) ? $options['script'] : '';
    return $base . $script . $query . $options['fragment'];
  }
```